# Network bound transformation and threading

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use a REST API to enrich data I have in a spark dataframe.  The REST API isn't built by me and requires a single input at a time (no batch option).  Unfortunately the REST API latency is slower than I would like so my spark applications seem to spend a lot of time waiting for the API to iterate over each row.  Although my REST API has higher latency, it does have very high throughput/capacity which does not seem to get fully used by my spark application.

Since my application appears to be network bound, I was wondering if it would make sense to use threading to help improve the speed of my application.  Does spark already capable of doing this internally?  If using threads does make sense, is there an easy way to accomplish this?  Has anybody successfully done this?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve encountered the same problem when fetching data from a blob storage.
Below is a small self-contained dummy example that I think you can easily modify for your needs.
In the example you should be able to register that it takes a lot longer to construct `df_slow` vs constructing `df_fast`.
It works by making each worker process a list of rows in parallel, instead of processing one row at a time sequentially.
You might be able to just swap the `slowAdd` function with your own *Row* transforming function. The `slowAdd` function simulates network latency by sleeping 0.1 seconds.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import Row
# Just some dataframe with numbers
data = [(i,) for i in range(0, 1000)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Data"], T.IntegerType())

# Get an rdd that contains 'list of Rows' instead of 'Row'
standardRdd =  df.rdd # contains [row1, row3, row3,...]
number_of_partitions = 10
repartionedRdd = standardRdd.repartition(number_of_partitions) # contains [row1, row2, row3,...] but repartioned to increase parallelism 
glomRdd = repartionedRdd.glom() # contains roughly [[row1, row2, row3,..., row100], [row101, row102, row103, ...], ...] 
                                # where the number of sublists corresponds to the number of partitions
  
# Define a transformation function with an artificial delay.
# Substitute this with your own transformation function.
import time
def slowAdd(r):
  d = r.asDict()
  d["Data"] = d["Data"] + 100
  time.sleep(0.1)
  return Row(**d)

# Define a function that maps the slowAdd function from 'list of Rows' to 'list of Rows' in parallel
import concurrent.futures
def slowAdd_with_thread_pool(list_of_rows):
  thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
  return [result for result in thread_pool.map(slowAdd, list_of_rows)]

# Perform a fast mapping from 'list of Rows' to 'Rows'.
transformed_fast_rdd = glomRdd.flatMap(slowAdd_with_thread_pool)

# For reference, perform a slow mapping from 'Rows' to 'Rows'
transformed_slow_rdd = repartionedRdd.map(slowAdd)

# Convert the rdds back to dataframes from the rdd's
df_fast = spark.createDataFrame(transformed_fast_rdd)
#This sum operation will be fast (~100 threads sleeping in parallel on each worker) 
df_fast.agg(F.sum(F.col("Data"))).show()

df_slow = spark.createDataFrame(transformed_slow_rdd)
#This sum operation will be slow (1 thread sleeping in parallel on each worker) 
df_slow.agg(F.sum(F.col("Data"))).show()
```